# What species is this blue and white bird?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

I want to know what kind of species this bird is 
[image]

Comment: Please add your location, where you got the birds, and an approximate size of the birds. A better photo would also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The bird in the photo appears to be a white faced "variety" of Lovebird - Genus Agapornis - mainly identified by beak and nares not being visible (cere skin and nostrils not visible). The exact species is uncertain due to ease of hybridization between species and the availability of many color varieties.  The links below may be of further help.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovebird#Species

https://www.agapornidenclub.be/eng/?page_id=2